# How to create UI5 Applications for SAP Business One using SAP Web IDE

Tags: odata, sapui5, sapb1

1. We are trying to use SAP Web IDE (WIDE) to develop UI5 applications. The back end is SAP Business One (B1). Currently B1 provides a service layer (B1SL) with which ODATA syntax can be used. However B1SL is not integrated with WIDE.
2. How can I retrieve the B1SL metadata.xml into WIDE? WIDE uses xml views, which depend on the associations and navigation properties defined in this metadata.xml.
3. What is the best way then to manually call B1SL, and manually form MVC models within WIDE? Should these calls be created within component.js?

Thanks. 
Chong Chin

Answer (score 0):

As its description states B1 SL supports REST http requests so you can employ jquery.ajax for retrieving and posting data via http, however you'd probably need to implement intermediate JSON model inside your SAPUI5 app to take advantage of data binding.

Comment: Hi slkorolev, Thank you. The issue here is that SAP promotes the use of xml views for Web IDE (although JS scripts can be use). All the SAP samples and the recent open SAP course "Developing Web Apps with SAPUI5) use xml views. The binding in xml views depending on the metadata.xml which defines the relationships among the entities. Please let me have links to code examples where REST calls are used in WEB IDE for a SAPB1 back end, if possible, with several entities. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Slkorolev, I tried recently to login to B1SL. Using Chrome Postman, there is no issue. We could login, get the sessionID, and then proceed with ODATA queries. However when we tried with Jquery Ajax, we had the a "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" error. We already have add the 2 entries, "CorsEnable", "CorsAllowedOrigins" in b1.conf file in at /usr/sap/SAPBusinessOne/ServiceLayer/conf. Any ideas what to try next? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Chong Chin, the idea is to load data via ajax into the runtime object and then bind the data to controls via JSON model you create at run time. 
Unfortunately I am no expert in B1 and cannot comment in its configuration, however there are quite a few references out there on CORS error: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/06/29/solving-same-origin-policy-issue-in-different-ways

Comment: Hi Slkorolev, I understand your approach and thank you for the link. The approach will probably mean using JavaScript views as compared to xml views. One advantage of xml views is a clearer separation between business logic and UI logic. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Chong Chin, actually the approach does not require to use JSON views, and thanks for letting me know of the xml view advantages.

Comment: HI Slkorolev, In the application I have, several sales orders are downloaded, Then when a user selects 1 sales order, data from several entities are shown on the same xml view - the sales order, its order items, customer and several rows of approval history. In xml view, I need to relate these entities together. Without the metadata.xml, I have to relate them manually and bind to the controls. If you find any links to similar to similar code examples, please let me know. Thanks for active help.